# Calling an EXE from a WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am working on a project where i need to run an executable once its reached the end of the WCF Method, I cant do this in the codebehind as the webservice will be set to oneway.

I have tried the following:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
  startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Test.exe";
  startInfo.Arguments = "Arg";
  process.StartInfo = startInfo;
  process.Start();
```

The WCF webservice doesn't throw any errors.

Is it possible to call executables from WCF or is there any alternative ways of doing this.

Comment: How are you sure it doesn't run?

Comment: It calls a exe file that i have created to copy some files from one location to another, if i run the exe by double clicking then the files are copied, if i do it via the WCf no files are copied

Comment: If you debug does it throw any exception? does the user that runs your application pool or your application in IIS has the right permissions to run test.exe program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between double clicking a program versus launching it from your WCF service is permissions.  When you double click the program, it runs under your account (which is probably administrator or super user) while launching from the WCF service will execute it under the service account associated with the WCF application or the app pool in which it resides (which is typically very restricted).

To test to see if this is the problem, ON DEV BOX ONLY, you can temporarily assign administrator as the app pool service account and see if it works.  Once you have confirmed that is the problem, restore the original account and tweak its permissions until the program works.

Another way to test it is to interactively sign on as the IIS account and double click the program.  This will let you see any errors that may be occurring when it is called from the service.

There are other potential problems (e.g. environment variables or current working directory that are different when running as yourself vs. as the WCF service) but I've found that permissions is usually the culprit.

Comment: Do you think it is a good Idea to run an exe file using WCF? I have a scenario where my employers wants me to scrap data using Selenium upon an http request. I have tried azure functions but was not able to run the selenium drivers from that.

Comment: No, it's not a great idea. I would only do it if the .exe already existed, out of pragmatism. If you have a choice I would find some other way to do it.

Comment: I was initially using Azure Function to trigger the .exe file. Then came to know that we cannot run selenium driver on it, Then I thought I should get a virtual machine and build a wcf service to run the chrome using wcf. Still seeing other things lets see what we get.